# List<string> returns as System.Collections.Generic.List on HttpPost wiht MVC

Tags: c#, list, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a Web App written in MVC5 which passes a List of an Object(which contains many items) to a Page and renders successfully.  I have a button on the form that forces a Post back.  When I click the button the model appears to re-initialise the List of Objects, rather than return what was is on the Page.

I have read various posts on SO that cover similar issues that have made many suggestion like ensuring every item in the Object is on the form (at least hidden).  Tried many of the options, but so far haven't been successful in solving my issue.

I decided to go back to basics on it, and created a very simple View Model with a List.  This again renders ok, but when returned it as System.Collections.Generic.List.

**View Model**

```
public class TestVm
{
    public List<string> CustomerNames { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    TestVm testmodel = new TestVm();

    testmodel.CustomerNames = new List<string>();
    testmodel.CustomerNames.Add("HELP");
    testmodel.CustomerNames.Add("Its");
    testmodel.CustomerNames.Add("Not");
    testmodel.CustomerNames.Add("Working");
    return View(testmodel); 
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(TestVm model)
{
    // DO SOME WORK HERE WITH RETURNED model
    return View(model);
}
```

**View**

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.TestVm
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>View</title>
</head>
<body>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Test", Model, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
    <button name="submit" type="submit" value="Refresh" class="btn btn-sm btn-default pull-right">Refresh</button>
}
<div>
@if (Model.CustomerNames != null)
{

<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center">CustomerName</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.CustomerNames.Count(); i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center">@Html.EditorFor(m => m.CustomerNames[i])</td>
            </tr>
        }
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I thought creating a simple app like this would help me understand and solve my issue.  But I can't work out why the model in the HttpPost contains "System.Collections.Generic.List", rather than the actual list of string that I would expect.

**Initial Loadup**
[Page when loaded up the first time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PV6lR.png)

**After Refresh**

[Page after I clicked Refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTAVI.png)

Comment: Because your form does not contain any form controls, noting is submitted to your POST method and the list is empty. As for the reason it then showing `System.Collections.Generic.List` - its due to the code you have not shown (`// DO SOME WORK HERE WITH RETURNED model`) - show the relevant code

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke for your reply.  There was no relevant code at that point, as I still have to write the code in that area.  The GenericList being returned was, as DPac suggested below, purely down to the location of my closing bracket for the "@Using" statement.

Comment: Yes I know (its in the first line of my previous comment) But that does not explain why you got `System.Collections.Generic.List` when you returned the view (which can only be due to another issue with code you have not shown)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enclose every form control under `Html.BeginForm` brackets

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Test", Model, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
    <button name="submit" type="submit" value="Refresh" class="btn btn-sm btn-default pull-right">Refresh</button>

    <div>
    @if (Model.CustomerNames != null)
    {

        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center">CustomerName</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.CustomerNames.Count(); i++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-center">@Html.EditorFor(m => m.CustomerNames[i])</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    }
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @DPac.  Changed my code to include everything within the <body> tags to be within the "@using {..}",  but it actually still returns the same result.

Comment: Just tried it again on my main app, and it works.  End bracket had to be moved.